# Is the stack aligned to a 4 bytes boundary when my program starts?

Tags: assembly, x86, stack, memory-alignment, calling-convention

I want to make sure that my variables are correctly aligned. So I have the following questions:

- When my program first starts, i.e. when my entry point starts
  executing, is the stack at this point aligned to a 4 bytes boundary?
  Or does that depends if I am linking against the CRT or not (I would
  guess that the CRT has its own entry point that calls my entry point,
  so this CRT entry point could adjust the stack alignment, or is an
  entry point added to my program either way?). Or I should not make
  any assumptions about the alignment of the stack and check
  the esp value myself?
- When I call a function, does this function expects the stack to be
  aligned, or does that depends on the calling convention?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On 32 bit systems, ESP passed to your program entry point is 4-byte aligned.  On 64 bit systems, it is 8 byte aligned.  This is guaranteed by the program loading/startup logic, which passes such an aligned ESP to your entry point.

Once your program starts execution, all functions (library, OS calls, and the ones  you will code) expect this alignment to be preserved, and virtually no code violates it.  (One reason why: misaligned stacks at best means misaligned accesses, which slows your program down.)

Comment: Downvoter: if you think this is wrong, then you should say why.

Comment: If I am calling a function, does this function expects the stack to be aligned based on its calling convention? for example, could one calling convention not care if the stack is aligned or not, while another mandates that it should be aligned to a 4 bytes boundary?

Comment: Most of the calling conventions don't call out explicit stack alignment.  They simply assume it.  Generally, because PUSH instructions push "q/dword" sized items, once the stack is aligned, stack operations will leave it aligned, so this is not hard to maintain.  As I said, on the x86 stack misalignments will cause a performance penalty so should be avoided for that reason alone.  Reading misaligned data is messy; the x86 has transistors to support it.  On non x86 architectures (e.g, MIPS) misaligned stacks (and other kinds of data accesses) either cause traps or undefined behavior.

Comment: If in my function (on x86) I want to create a `double` local variable, I should first check the esp for an 8 bytes alignment, and if it's not aligned to an 8 bytes boundary, I should add the required padding, right?

Comment: On a 32 bit system, in general you don't need to align a double local ("in stack") on an 8 byte boundary.  You *might* wish to do so, to avoid the penalty of accessing the 2-DWORD value if it happened to span a cache line or a page boundary.  As a practical matter, in the stack, a variable might cross a cache line boundary but both cache-line chunks are likely to likely to be in the cache anyway because of the LIFO properties of the stack.  Trying to align this dynamically will cost you runtime in all circumstances, to save runtime occassionally.  In general, not worth it.  YMMV.

Comment: If the code is in assembly, then the normal prologue | push ebp | mov ebp,esp | just needs one more instruction: | and ebp,0fffffff8h | . I don't know if there are compiler options to do this.

Comment: @rcgdlr:  Yes, that's one approach.   It doesn't matter a lot because all the memory blocks for the area around the top of the stack are highly likely to already be in the cache.    You can generalize this so that each function call "allocates" its own cache line in the stack using "and ebp,-cachelinesize".   For a function that is heavily used, this means its locals are very likely to be in just one cache line, minimize cache line demand.